# SWRevealViewController from modal segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealViewController after following AppCoda's [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/). I was able to get it working in the tutorial with no issues, but not able to adapt it to my own app. The reason is that in my app I don't use the SWRevealVC from the initial screen. The menu button to trigger the SWRevealVC doesn't appear until after a modal segue from the main screen. So from the main scene there is a modal segue to a new scene (RecipeDetailVC) which contains the menu button in the upper left to trigger the SWRevealVC. RecipeDetailsVC has its custom segue's identifier set as the front viewcontroller (sw_front). Nothing happens when I tap the menu button, no error or crash, but it just doesn't do anything. I'm sure the reason is that the RevealVC is dangling out there as you can see in the storyboard. Also, I made sure to set its class to the SWRevealVC class. Also, in the RecipeDetailsVC, which is the front VC, the (revealViewController) code in viewDidLoad never evaluates which is why nothing is happening when tapping the menu button. I'm sure this is related the dangling revealVC, but not sure how to correct it. Can anyone tell me how to correct this for this scenario? Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad...");
    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if (revealViewController)
    {
        NSLog(@"DEBUG: We have a revealVC!");
        [self.sidebarButton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
        [self.sidebarButton setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWRevealViewController should be the root view controller of the front and rear view controller. Try performing modal segue to the SWRevealViewController and not to the RecipeDetailVC navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks...so just control drag from the menu button in RecipeDetailsVC to SWRevealVC, set the front and rear view controllers programmatically and do a peformSegue call?

Comment: No. Right now it looks like you have a model segue from the main scene to the RecipeDetailVC. Try make that from main scene to the SWRevealViewController. This is not tested, but it the first thing I'd try. Hope it'll work.

Comment: I don't think that will work but I'll play around with it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it?? I tested it on my project and it works.

Comment: Didn't have a chance, but I'm still not sure exactly how to do what you're talking about. Can you share with me what you did? Thanks!

Comment: In your question you said "So from the main scene there is a modal segue to a new scene (RecipeDetailVC)". You just simply delete that segue, and then create a new segue by control dragging from the main scene to the Reveal View Controller. That makes the RVC the root view controller of the new scene. Right now RecipeDetailVC is the root view controller of your new scene, that's why, like you said, RVC is just dangling there doing nothing. If you look at the tutorial, you can see that RVC is the root view controller, and not the front view controller. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It definitely makes sense. I just need to play with it to make sure I can modify it to fit. This is a side project and I haven't had the time to really sit down and go through it. I should be able to over the weekend. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I finally got around to trying your suggestion but could not get it to work! Here's what I did based on your suggestion...I deleted the modal segue from the main scene to RecipeDetailsVC. I control dragged from main scene to SWRevealVC. I then set the front view controller of the SWReveal (RecipeDetailsVC) and the rear view controller (SidebarVC). I made sure the identifier of the segue I deleted was set as the modal segue of the SWReveal. The result is it crashes in loadStoryBoardControllers of SWRevealVC. What am I missing? Thanks again.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. For some reason it was crashing on the loadStoryboardControllers on the try/catch block for the SWSegueRightIdentifier segue. I commented that out and it worked. Thanks for the help. I accepted your answer.